# Getting footer and header in an external script?

Tags: magento-1.9, header, footer

**Magento 1.9**

I created an external script in my root folder. It contains these lines in order to work:

```
require '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
```

How can I get the header and footer? Is it possible at all?

Comment: try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/287200/82670

Comment: Thanks, but thats for Magento 2, I need that for Magento 1.